# Using MouseEvents to change chart series appearance in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, charts, legend

I have a point chart in my form which is created dynamically so the number/name of the series on the chart can change on each run of the form.  I'd like to be able to highlight a series using the legend in order to better see the points that belong to that series only.  I have been able to highlight the series using a thicker marker border but I have not been able to make it so that this highlight is removed either on another click or moving off the legend item.  Here's how I highlight the points in a selected series:

```
            private void plot.MouseMove (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
                    {
                        HitTestResult result = plot.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
                        if (result != null && result.Object != null)
                        {
                            if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.LegendItem)
                            {
                                string selseries = result.Series.Name;
                                plot.Series[selseries].MarkerBorderWidth = 3;
                                plot.Series[selseries].MarkerSize = 11;
                                plot.Series[selseries].MarkerBorderColor = Color.Black;
                            }
                        }

                    };
```

How can I deselect this once it has been highlighted?  Is there a better way to go about selectively highlighting one series as compared to others?  Ideally I'd like to make all series other than the one selected change to a dimmer color thus highlighting the series in question but I'll settle for being able to select/deselect the series in question.

Comment: Does this `plot.MouseMove` compile?

Comment: If you want to revert changes you need to a) remember or b) find out which series you changed by looking at the current values of all series. And you need to know the old values. Both is not really hard to do. Other than that you are doing fine imo.. Best write a function `void hilightSeries(Series s, bool hilite)` to turn it on/off..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "remember" which series you highlighted, you need to store a reference outside of this method so that you can access it later.  Then, whenever you want to clear the changes, just look for whatever you saved earlier and reset the properties.  Here is some example code:

```
string selectedSeries = "";     // store a class-scoped reference

private void plot.MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult result = plot.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    if (result != null && result.Object != null && result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.LegendItem)
    {
        string selseries = result.Series.Name;

        // store a reference to what we are changing:
        selectedSeries = selseries;

        plot.Series[selseries].MarkerBorderWidth = 3;
        plot.Series[selseries].MarkerSize = 11;
        plot.Series[selseries].MarkerBorderColor = Color.Black;
    }
    else
    {
        // if we clear the selection here, then we are clearing the selection
        // whenever we move off the legend item... that was one of your use cases
        // you could also do something similar in a mouse click event to cover your other use case.

        if (selectedSeries != "")
        {
            plot.Series[selectedSeries].MarkerBorderWidth = 1; // set these to default value
            plot.Series[selectedseries].MarkerSize = 5;
            plot.Series[selectedseries].MarkerBorderColor = Color.Green;
            selectedSeries = ""; // reset selection
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `string selseries`  wouldn't be necessary in your scenario.  It's probably best to make sure the selectSeries key is valid in the plot.Series collection.

Comment: @LarsTech - this is true.  I was trying to make minimal changes to the existing code, but `selectedSeries` could be used directly in place of `selseries`, and some additional validation would be smart.

Comment: Thanks all!  I'm going to mark the answer as correct as I did something very similar.  I read TaW's reply and had already been trying to go down the path of finding which series had been changed.  I'm not sure what went wrong but now under where I call out `selseries` I add an if/else check based on the selected series markersize.  I also made it a MouseClick event instead of MouseMove as I think the small space between legend items was causing it to select/deselect when unwanted.